# react component responsiveness - change state on main render element resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Got a react.js component, that renders 3 Buttons that are aligned horizontally on an AppBar.

Menu lables are shortened on state changes, however, how can i change those states when the parent div element size changes, just before the child elemets (Buttons) would begin to align vertically (stack upon each other, instead of beeing aligned horizontally)? So basically its about catching the event of the main div elemtent not beeing wide enought to have the Buttons be aligned horizontally.

What is a proper way to accomplish what I intend to do?

```
return(
    <div>
        <Button color="inherit" variant={this.state.btnVar0} onClick={(e) => this.toggleMenuBtns(0,e)}><span className = {classes.menuButtonMed}  >M{this.state.squeeze > 1 ? null : <span  >ed</span>}</span>{this.state.squeeze > 0 ? null : <span>icine</   span>}</Button>
        <Button color="inherit" variant={this.state.btnVar1} onClick={(e) => this.toggleMenuBtns(1,e)}><span className = {classes.menuButtonTreat}>D{this.state.squeeze > 1 ? null : <span>ia</span>}</span>{this.state.squeeze > 0 ? null : <span>gnose</span>}</Button>
        <Button color="inherit" variant={this.state.btnVar2} onClick={(e) => this.toggleMenuBtns(2,e)}><span className = {classes.menuButtonCom}  >W{this.state.squeeze > 1 ? null : <span  >ell</span>}</span>{this.state.squeeze > 0 ? null : <span>ness</span>}</Button>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: The proper way is to handle this scanario using css, u can use flex properties for this or use media queries.

Comment: @RohithMurali: isnt this about content? how can this be done via css? do you have an example for me or a link to it? sry, I am not that of an experienced dev.